# Primefaces rowselect event doesnt work in ver 3.3

Tags: primefaces

I have this code. It should fire rowSelect event, after the user select a row and close the dialog box. it worked fine before i updated to primfaces 3.3(I had ver3.2). I dont have any exception in console and when I debuged i see the method doesnt call. I dont know where to begin to solv this problem. Could someone help me with this?

```
<p:dialog id="dlg" closable="true" header="New reciever" widgetVar="receiverListDlg" visible="false" modal="true">
        <p:dataTable var="reciever" value="#{transactionController.recieverList}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{transactionController.onRowSelect}" update=":form" onsuccess="receiverListDlg.hide()" />
            <f:facet name="header">  
            Previouse recievers for #{customer.firstName}   
        </f:facet>
            <p:column selectionMode="single" />

            <p:column headerText="#{msg.havale_customer_firstname}">
                <h:outputText value="#{reciever.firstName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg.havale_customer_lastName}">
                <h:outputText value="#{reciever.lastName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg.havale_customer_phoneNr}">
                <h:outputText value="#{reciever.phoneNr}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 7):

Now Primefaces provided some new ajax events:

- onSelectCheckBox
- onUnselectCheckbox
- onSelectRadio

So `rowSelect` and `rowUnselect` will not be fired in your case.

Comment: The events are called rowSelectCheckbox, rowUnselectCheckbox and rowSelectRadio.

Comment: Gosh I've spent a whole afternoon on this! Where did you find it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use the "rowSelectRadio" ajax event.

Answer (score 2):

The dataTable should be surrounded by `<h:form>`. Also you should add the following attributes to the p:dataTable (I don't know if all of them are required, but I have them all and it works fine).
- `selectionMode="single"` 
- `rowKey="#{receiver.id`}" (replace 'id' with the actual ID attribute of Receiver)
- `selection="#{transactionController.selectedReceiver"`

Comment: Thats working but i want that when you select the radiobutton it fires the rowSelect event which it did in the previouse versjon.

Comment: for the radioButton selection you also need to include these attributes. did you add them? is the table surrounded by a h:form? still rowSelect not fired?

Comment: Yes but it doesnt work in 3.3. I can make selection without radiobutton. It doesnt need surrounding form  only selectionMode="single" selection="#{transactionController.selectedReceiver"

Comment: surrounding form is for allowing ajax execute a method in the backing bean. did you try version 3.3.1? it includes some bug fixes

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to stackoverflow as user but I use it frequently as I saw that is something going on here with Prime! ;-)
Okay, I'm currently migrating a RichFaces 3.3.3 JSF 1.2 project to Mojarra 2.1.7 (SNAPSHOT 20120206) and PrimeFaces 3.3 which is IMHO revelation to JSF.
Long story short I was searching for this error mentioned in the topic for half the week and I gave it a try to step back to PF 3.2 and tataaaa rowSelect and all my other implementations work now.
I have a simple form with a datatable and selectionMode="multiple" and the ajax events:

```
        <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="massnahmenAuswahl"
            value="#{massnahmenController.massnahmen}"
            var="eineMassnahme"
            selection="#{massnahmenController.massnahmenSelected}"
            rowKey="#{eineMassnahme.massnahme}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                listener="#{massnahmenController.rowSelected}" process="@this"
                update="@this" />
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"
                listener="#{massnahmenController.rowUnselected}" process="@this"
                update="@this" />
            <p:ajax event="toggleSelect"
                listener="#{massnahmenController.rowToggleSelected}" process="@this"
                update="@this" />
            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px"
                disabledSelection="#{!login.editable}" styleClass="checkbox" />
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{eineMassnahme.zeile}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{eineMassnahme.bezeichnung}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <fiona:labelImgGA for="#{eineMassnahme.massnahme}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{eineMassnahme.vorjahr}"
                    disabled="true" />
            </p:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Speichern"
                    action="#{massnahmenController.speichern}"
                    disabled="#{!login.editable}" process="@this" update="@form" />
                <p:spacer/>
                <p:commandButton value="Weiter"
                    action="#{massnahmenController.saveAndNext}"
                    disabled="#{!login.editable}" process="@this" update="@form" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Will this be fixed in near future?
Until now I really go with PF!
Don't disappoint me! ;-)

UPDATE:
The solution is to use lazy=true since PF 3.3. I've seen it in issue [2993](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2993) in PrimeFaces issue tracker!

Comment: That issue isn't really related. Your problem is that with PF 3.3 you're supposed to use rowSelectCheckbox instead of rowSelect if you're using checkbox selection.